# Element between two containers

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i'm developping a website with bootstrap 4, i want to position a map between two containers.I putted the map in the second container and used the position relative and absolute way,(i made the row position relative and the div that contains the map as position absolute).The map appeared under the first container.I used the negative margin way, with the z-index.

[Click here for screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4yLN.jpg)

The grey part of the pictures,is the first container and the white part is the second container.
Helpppppp

Comment: First of all, please go read [ask]. And then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: You should Provide Code Example first.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For Map, use z-index = 1

For Grey Container, use z-index = -1

That might solve your problem.

It would really help if you could just provide the snippet of the code.

Comment: Thank you 3Demon so much, it worked.